# Ajax javascript post to Google Spreadsheet without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to get help with using ajax without jQuery to post data info a Google spreadsheet please.

As in jQuery it is really simple and goes like this:

```
var gformUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abcdefg1234567890/formResponse';

var gformData = {
    'entry.1405357202': 'text #1',
    'entry.2112718259': 'text #2',
    'entry.1657451952': 'text #3',
    'entry.737451165': 'text #4'
};

$.post(gformUrl,gformData);
```

Now even that it shows an error in the console for no cross origin, it still works great.

I'm trying to do not use jQuery and do that in pure javascript, but with no success just yet, here's my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', gformUrl, true);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(gformData));
```

Comment: You said you were getting a cross origin error, but the `$.post()` method still works by adding those entries in your spreadsheet?

Comment: YEP! the wonders of jQuery I guess ;)
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abcdefg1234567890/formResponse. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$.post()` is working even with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error, the culprit is likely to be the type of data that is being sent. According to the MDN article on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), a simple cross site request with POST requires the content-type of the data to be either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.

Currently, your `XMLHttpRequest()` sends JSON with a content-type of `text/html`. Let's fix that.

Knowing this, below is what you can try by setting the `content-type` request header to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and sending encoded data.

--EDIT-- Changed my previous `xhr.send(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(gformData)));` to Barmar's solution with my own twist to avoid the use of an array.

```
var gformUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abcdefg1234567890/formResponse';

var gformData = {
    'entry.1405357202': 'text #1',
    'entry.2112718259': 'text #2',
    'entry.1657451952': 'text #3',
    'entry.737451165': 'text #4'
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', gformUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

var formData = '';
for (var key in gformData) {
    formData += encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(gformData[key]) + '&';
}
xhr.send(formData.substr(0, formData.length-1));
```

Comment: So combine your answer (setting a request header) together with @Barmar code that convert the JSON info a URL-encoded format, did the job.

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` sends the data in URL-encoded format, not JSON. This is `param=val&param=val&...` format.

```
var formDataArray = [];
for (var key in gformData) {
    formDataArray.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(gformData[key]));
}
xhr.send(formDataArray.join('&');
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it still doesn't works and just gives the cross origin error in the console as in jQuery but not working.
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abcdefg1234567890/formResponse. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: As @boombox mentioned there is a need to set  a request header, combine that with your code solved the issue, so thanks :)